# "Object Required" Error After Declaring Excel.Application object

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am receiving an "object required" error while writing a VBScript to run a macro outside of Excel. The code is below this message. After declaring `xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, any attempted action on the `xlApp` object will throw the "object required" error.

Am I missing something in my declaration statement, or is there some sort of import/include statement I need to make?

```
Sub temp()

  Dim xlApp, xlBook
  Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  oShell.CurrentDirectory = "H:"
  MsgBox (oShell.CurrentDirectory)

  xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.Visible = True 'error is thrown here
  xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("H:\SW Tool Resources\test\tester.xlsm")
  MsgBox ("Success")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `Set` your object variable to the new instance of Excel:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```